# IIS Express fails when Azure Web Role start

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure, azure-web-roles

I have Asp.Net MVC web application. It works fine when I run it on Local IIS or IIS Express.
I deployed it as Azure Web Site. It works fine.

Now I want to deploy application as Azure Cloud Service. I add Azure Cloud Service project to my solution. Then I add Web Role from existing web project.

When I run my solution under Azure Emulator it does not work. I have an error "IIS Express Worker Process has stopped working". In Windows event viewer I have only IIS Crashed error, without any details.
In task manager I have Windows Azure Emulator, but I have no IIS express with my web role.

But when I deploy my solution to azure cloud service, it works like a charm. I'm confused what is wrong. One more point. If I create new web-application in my solution and create web role for new project, then it works fine!

I'm confused what is wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I have this block in my web.config file

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
    <add initializationPage="/" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

This cause the IIS Express crashing when web role started.

Hope this helps anybody else.